# Authenticating with AWS AssumedRole in JS AWS SDK v3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sts

I'm having problems understanding how authentication is supposed to work in AWS SDK v3. My use case requires me to provide temporary credentials generated on the backend to the frontend app (js, BROWSER!) so it can access very specific and dynamically determined AWS resources (like a directory in an S3 bucket).

`aws sts assume-role` seems like the perfect fit for the backend call, but I can't find a way to authenticate in browser js AWS SDK v3 using `SecretAccessKey`, `SessionToken` and `AccessKeyId`, though it used to be there in v2.

Am I missing something? Or is the suggested flow different than what I'm looking for?

Comment: I think you're saying that your client requests STS credentials from your backend but you don't know how to supply those credentials to an SDK method to create a session or client object. Each client constructor has a client config option that has a credentials property (example for S3 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/s3clientconfig.html)). Also, consider looking at Amplify.

Comment: @jarmod yes, my BE makes an appropriate `aws sts assume-role` (or equivalent using an SDK) call upon request and returns `SecretAccessKey`, `SessionToken` and `AccessKeyId`, which I would like the client to use to authenticate and access e.g. S3. Thank you very much for your tip, I think this part of the docs was much clearer in v2. Also most examples point to cognito, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: There is also the option to set [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html) prior to launching your app and the v3 SDK will automatically load them. Not sure that would work for you, but it's an available option.

Comment: aren't the env vars only appropriate for node.js? Do browser applications even have access to env vars?

Comment: You're correct, they're only relevant to backend. Forgot for a minute that your client was in-browser. Were you able to make progress? Agree that the v3 SDK and docs are more challenging than v2.

Comment: @mpnowacki I'm running into the same issue for an authenticated S3 download via assumed role temporary credentials. Did you find a solution?